# Non-standard partial orders on root systems

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems

Let $\frak{g}$ be a semisimple complex Lie algebra and let $\Delta$ be its associated root system with $\{\alpha_1, \dotsc, \alpha_l\}$ a choice of positive roots. As we all know - $\Delta$ admits a partial order defined by $\alpha > \beta$ if $\alpha - \beta$ is a positive root. Do there exist other interesting, or well motivated, partial (or total) orders on $\Delta$. For example take the following ordering: For any root $\beta = \sum_i m_i \alpha_i$ and take the *length function*
$$
\lambda(\beta) := \sum_i m_i.
$$
Now declare $\beta > \beta'$ if $\lambda(\beta) > \lambda(\beta')$. Is this partial ordering of any importance?

Comment: To answer your last question: the partial order you define at the end does not seem to be of any importance.

Answer (score 8):

Another partial order which comes up a lot is to take the transitive closure of the relation that, if $\langle \alpha_i, \beta \rangle < 0$, then $\beta \prec s_i(\beta)$.

For example, consider $B_2$ with short root $\alpha$ and long root $\beta$. The partial order you describe in your question is
$$\alpha,\ \beta < \alpha+\beta < 2 \alpha+ \beta.$$
The partial order I have described above is the weaker (fewer relations) order:
$$\alpha \prec \alpha+\beta,\ \ \beta \prec 2 \alpha+\beta.$$

This latter order has the advantage of being defined in the non-crystallographic types, and being independent of the Cartan matrix.

Comment: Sorry for a foolish misunderstanding—what does "independent of the Cartan matrix" mean?  Doesn't the root system determine the Cartan matrix?

Comment: @LSpice Sorry, that was shorthand for the following: A Coxeter group is a group with generators $s_i$ and relations $s_i^2 = 1$, $(s_i s_j)^{m_{ij}} = 1$. A reflection is an element of $W$ conjugate to an $s_i$. The set of reflections is called $T$; the set of simple reflections is called $S$.

Comment: A Cartan matrix for $W$ is a matrix obeying certain conditions, like $A_{ij} A_{ji} = 4 \cos^2 \tfrac{\pi}{m_{ij}}$. It gives rise to a representation $V$ of $W$ and (if $A$ is crystallographic) a root system in $V$. The positive roots are then in bijection with the reflections of $W$.

Comment: Ah, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/432296/non-standard-partial-orders-on-root-systems/432299#comment1112683_432299), so you mean something like, it doesn't see the difference between $\mathsf B_n$ and $\mathsf C_n$?

Comment: Exactly. "Independent of the Cartan matrix" is usually abusive shorthand for "can be defined as a relation on $T$, solely in terms of $W$ and $S$.

Comment: In this case, I think the relation on $T$ is the transtitive closure of $t \prec sts$ if $\ell(t) < \ell(sts)$, though I'm not sure.